# Google Cloud Storage creating content links with inconsistent behavior

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a project using Google Cloud Storage to allow users to upload media files into a predefined bucket using Node.js. I've been testing with small `.jpg` files. I also used `gsutil` to set bucket permissions to public.

At first, all files generated links that downloaded the file. Upon investigation of the docs, I learned that I could explicitly set the `Content-Type` of each file after upload using the `gsutil` CLI. When I used this procedure to set the filetype to `'image/jpeg'`, the link behavior changed to display the image in the browser. But this only worked if the link had not been previously clicked prior to updating the metadata with `gsutil`. I thought that this might be due to browser caching, but the behavior was duplicated in an incognito browser.

Using `gsutil` to set the mime type would be impractical at any rate, so I modified the code in my node server `POST` function to set the metadata at upload time using an `npm` module called `mime`. Here is the code:

```
app.post('/api/assets', multer.single('qqfile'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);

    if (!req.file) {
        return ('400 - No file uploaded.');
    }

    // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
    var blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
    var blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
    var metadata = {
        contentType: mime.lookup(req.file.originalname)
    };

    blobStream.on('error', function (err) {
        return next(err);
    });

    blobStream.on('finish', function () {

        blob.setMetadata(metadata, function(err, response){
            console.log(response);
             // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
        var publicUrl = format(
        'https://storage.googleapis.com/%s/%s',
        bucket.name, blob.name);
        res.status(200).send(
            {
                'success': true,
                'publicUrl': publicUrl,
                'mediaLink': response.mediaLink
            });
        });

    });

    blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);

});
```

This seems to work, from the standpoint that it does actually set the `Content-Type` on upload, and that is correctly reflected in the response object as well as the Cloud Storage console. The issue is that some of the links returned as `publicUrl` cause a file download, and others cause a browser load of the image. Ideally I would like to have both options available, but I am unable to see any difference in the stored files or their metadata.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage makes no assumptions about the content-type of uploaded objects. If you don't specify, GCS will simply assign a type of "application/octet-stream".

The command-line tool `gsutil`, however, is smarter, and will attach the right Content-Type to files being uploaded in most cases, JPEGs included.

Now, there are two reasons why your browser is likely to download images rather than display them. First, if the Content-Type is set to "application/octet-stream", most browsers will download the results as a file rather than display them. This was likely happening in your case.

The second reason is if the server responds with a 'Content-Disposition: attachment' header. This doesn't generally happen when you fetch GCS objects from the host "storage.googleapis.com" as you are doing above, but it can if you, for instance, explicitly specified a contentDisposition for the object that you've uploaded.

For this reason I suspect that some of your objects don't have an "image/jpeg" content type. You could go through and set them all with gsutil like so:  `gsutil -m setmeta 'Content-Type:image/jpeg' gs://myBucketName/**`

Comment: I went through and verified that all files are correctly tagged with the appropriate mime-type, and none are tagged `application-octet-stream`. Additionally, I verified that the 'Content-Disposition' value was not set, but just for overkill explicitly added a line in the server code to tag that as null in the metadata. On a whim, I duplicated one of the `. jpg` files and changed the extension to `.jpeg`. The `.jpeg` file loads correctly, while the `.jpg` version still downloads. Exact same file. But others with a `.jpg` extension work just fine.

Comment: Interesting. And that's using URLs that are just "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/imageName.jpg" or "imageName.jpeg" in a browser?

Comment: That is correct. I just ran another test where I explicitly added a `'Content-Disposition'` value of 'inline' to the metadata on upload. I deleted all files in storage, and reloaded both of the `.jpeg` variants described above. The response object *and* the Cloud Storage console verify that the mime-type and disposition are set as expected. Only this time, I'm getting the exact opposite behavior. The `.jpeg` file displays in-browser, while the `.jpg` version downloads. Frustrating!

Comment: These are publicly readable objects, yes? If so, you may be getting bitten by caching. By default, publicly readable objects can be cached for up to an hour (you can override this by setting the cacheControl property on the object or just making your request with superfluous extra URL parameters).

Comment: I think that this is the answer. Evidently there is a default 3600 sec. cache lifespan on objects in these buckets. Adding a metadata field of `cacheControl: 'no-cache'` had no effect on items that had already been cached even after being deleted and reloaded. But when I appended the value of `?ignoreCache=1` to the URI, the content rendered properly in the browser. I suspect that this will be a non-issue in actual usage, as the cache will reset after an hour. Thanks for the help running this to ground!

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it! So for the record, the underlying issue was the contentType, but figuring that out was masked because of the default one hour cache?

Comment: That seems to be the case.